# Wordpress search also shows

Tags: algolia

I'm trying Agolia to see if it is something for our websites. So I did a little test on one of our websites ([click here](https://eezo.nl/overzicht/blog/geld-verdienen-wifi-netwerk-zonder-gasten-laten-betalen/), it works but you also get the original dropdown. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme you are using does come shipped with a built-in autocomplete experience.

You should disable that one.

An easy fix for you would be to comment all the code in this file https://eezo.nl/wp-content/themes/yoo_venice_wp/warp/vendor/uikit/js/components/search.js